# tooltiptext for dropdown list inside tablelayoutpanel

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, tablelayoutpanel

language is vb.net.
I have a TableLayoutPanel. I have dynamically added combobox dropdownlist into it
when dropdownlist popuates, its items are not fully visible.
how do i add tooltip text to all items when i move mouse over the items.
how can i use this below code in my code and at what point or position should i use this.
this code is from internet

```
public static void SetToolTip(DropDownList cmb)
{
    if (cmb.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in cmb.Items)
        {
            item.Attributes.Add("Title", item.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is for Web Forms, not Windows Forms.

Comment: how do i write in vb.net winforms. can you please help

Comment: A better idea might be to set the `DropDownWidth` dynamically too, based on the width of the items.

Comment: There is no managed API for adding tool tips to `ComboBox` items.  It may be able to be done but there would not be any simple way.